# How to write predicate that checks whether for two same X values there are different Y values?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate in Prolog that should work with a set of facts like these:

```
value(a,b)
value(d,f)
value(p,k)
```

Where the first value is X and second is Y. And it should write whether there are two same X values among those facts that have different Y values. In the example above the predicate should return true and in the example below the predicate should return false.

```
value(a,b)
value(d,f)
value(a,k)
```

My current predicate is this

```
have_different_Y_for_same_X :- relation(X, Y), not(relation(X, Z)).
```

All results I get no matter the values are true, so it's not working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a problem with the negation: you want it to be true if there are **no** such relation for an `X` and two different `Y`. The following code gives the desired result.

```
different_Y_for_same_X() :- 
    value(X, Y), 
    value(X, Z),
    Y @< Z.

no_different_Y_for_same_X() :- 
    \+ different_Y_for_same_X().
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First in `checkX` it collects all X's in XList.

2- In `checkX1` For each X collects it's Y's in YList.

3- Then finally in `checkX2`, for each X checks if it's Y's are same or not using `same` predicate.

```
value(a,b).
value(d,f).
value(a,k).

checkX:-
    findall(X1,value(X1,_),XList),
    checkX1(XList,YList),
    checkX2(XList,YList).
    
checkX1([],[]).
checkX1([H|T],[YList|List]):-
    findall(Y,value(H,Y),YList),
    checkX1(T,List).

checkX2([],[]).
checkX2([H|T],[H2|T2]):-
    (   
    \+same(H2)->  
    write('X='),
    write(H),
    write(' '),
    write('Y='),
    writeln(H2),
    writeln('true'),
    checkX2(T,T2);
    write('X='),
    write(H),
    write(' '),
    write('Y='),
    writeln(H2),
    writeln('false'),
    checkX2(T,T2)).

same([]).   % You only need this one if you want the empty list to succeed
same([_]).
same([X,X|T]) :- same([X|T]).
```

**Example:**

```
?-checkX
X=a Y=[b, k]
true
X=d Y=[f]
false
X=a Y=[b, k]
true
1true
```

---

Here's my approach:

**1-** Define the facts.

**2-** `checkX` predicate finds all Y values for X using `findall`. It returns a list `(YList=[b,k])`.

**3-** Then check that the elements in the list are not same, using `(\+)` for not.

```
value(a,b).
value(d,f).
value(a,k).

checkX(X):-
    findall(Y,value(X,Y),YList),
    \+same(YList).
    
same([]).   % You only need this one if you want the empty list to succeed
same([_]).
same([X,X|T]) :- same([X|T]).
```

**Example:**

```
?-checkX(a).
1true
```

Now suppose I have the following facts:

```
value(a,k).
value(d,f).
value(a,k).

?-checkX(a).
false
```

Comment: This solution is great, however, I wanted to make predicate that does this for all X and finds whether for any two same X there are different Y values without having to type the X argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff_2nds(X) :-
    value(X, Y1), value(X, Y2),
    Y1 \= Y2.
```

Just write exactly what you mean. `value/2` must succeed twice with different values.
This gives

```
?- diff_2nds(X).
X = a ;
X = a ;
false.
```